# Node.js Server (Mobile Client)

Tags: mysql, node.js, delphi, mobile, firemonkey

I am trying to make a Data Monitoring with Mobile App.
I have a mysql database and i am planning use Node.js  server.
My project:
Node.js server connect to mysql db. 
Mobile apps connect to node.js server and when the new data add to mysql, node.js server send to data mobile apps using restful service.

Is it possible to communicate between node.js server and firemonkey mobile client apps? (I' ll build mobile apps via firemonkey - Delphi)

Comment: yes you can use push notifications to tell your app that new data is ready, then make that app request the data.  Other solution would be to keep websocket open and listen but it is highly expensive battery wise and shall be avoided.

Comment: So my system like: mySQL -> Node.js(Server) -> GCM(Push Not.) -> Mobile Apps(IOS, Android) is it true?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[image]

The reason to use push notifications, is so that your Mobile app does not waste resources to maintain constant connection to the server awaiting for new data, whether it is a web socket or a check for new data.

Keep in mind that Push notifications code might be different for [Android](http://developer.android.com/google/gcm/index.html) and [iOS](https://developer.apple.com/notifications/) platforms.